# Get common records from a join

Tags: t-sql, join

I have 2 tables - users and userbooks:

```
USERID  USERNAME  (USERS)
 --------  -------
 1         User1
 2         User2
 3         User3
 .         UserX

ID   USERID    BOOKID (USERBOOKS)
---  --------  -------
 1     1         1
 2     2         1
 3     3         1
 4     2         2
 5     2         2
 .   userx      bookx
```

I would like to get the common records (common read books read by every user) in this example getting the users who read book 1, but of course book id-s always vary

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, you are looking for `exists`:

```
SELECT UserId, UserName  
FROM Users
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM UserBooks
    WHERE UserBooks.UserId = USERS.UserId
    AND BookId = 1
)
```

This will return all the users that have corresponding records in UserBooks with the bookId 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @BOOK INT = 2;

SELECT UB.BOOKID,U.USERNAME,COUNT(*) AS TIMES 
FROM @USERBOOKS UB
INNER JOIN @USERS U ON UB.USERID = U.USERID
WHERE UB.BOOKID = @BOOK
GROUP BY BOOKID,U.USERNAME
ORDER BY 1,2 
;
```

Note that Book ID 2 was used twice by User2